# Cannot define a specific branch as a requirement with composer

Tags: composer-php

I am having some trouble with using a specific branch as a dependency in my project.

I have one reposityry I'll call `repositoryA` which is the project I'm woring on, and `repositoryB` which is a different repository upon which `repositoryA` depends.

However, I have a specific branch in `repositoryB` named "1.0" that I want to specify for composer to use.

What I have tried in `repositoryA` is to, in composer.json, specify the following as a requirement (treat this as though each line is in different attempts, not in the same file/attempt):

```
// ...
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "1.0-dev",
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "1.0.x-dev",
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "dev-1.0",
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "dev-1.0.x",
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "1.0",
"my-vendor/repositoryB": "1.0.x",
// ...
```

When I try to set these constraints, then the error message I'm getting is:

```
The requested package my-vendor/repositoryB 1.0.x-dev exists as  
my-vendor/repositoryB[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

After googling this issue for a bit, it seemed like I need an alias for the "1.0"-branch for it to worked, so I also tried adding the following to the composer.json in `repositoryB`:

```
//...
"extra": {
  "branch-alias": {
    "1.0-dev": "1.0.x-dev"
  }
}
//...
```

What is it I'm misunderstanding in how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

Turns out that I could get it to work by first updating the branch in `composer.lock` to `1.0.x-dev` manually before running `composer update`.

Comment: That does not make any sense.. are you sure you were running `composer update` and not `composer install`?

Comment: I'm positive. I don't really understand why it's the case myself, but as soon as I updated it manually in the lock file, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tag your branch and use this tag in composer. No need to use branch-alias composer feature in this case.

Comment: I can only tag branches at a specific commit though, right? Meaning, I would need to tag all new versions in `repositoryB` for them to be available on `composer update`? (As opposed to it being available when the commits are merged into the branch)

Comment: Yes you need to tag all new versions https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Answer (score 1):

If your branch is named `1.0`, then a constraint of `1.0.x-dev` should work (see also docs on [branches](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches)). If it does not work, then you need to tell us what error composer is returning, because we cannot help you if you do not provide us all the relevant information.

Comment: When I try to set `1.0.x-dev` as the constraint, the error I'm getting is: `The requested package my-vendor/repositoryB 1.0.x-dev exists as my-vendor/repositoryB[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.`. I'll update the post with this.

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't have a `1.0` branch, but only `master`, and master has the `branch-alias` set to `1.0.x`. In that case, simply change your requirement to `dev-master`.

Comment: The repository does have multiple branches where one is named `1.0` and another `master`, and it is the one named `1.0` I'm interested in using. `dev-master` works fine, but it's not the wanted result.